# pagination in author.php template returns 404 error

Tags: query-posts, pagination, query, author

Hi to the community!!!

I need some help with pagination in author.php template.
I have pagination working in all my loops except in authors.php that i get a 404 error.
In my settings/reading i have set blog posts to show as 1.

The first step was the author rewrite from author to artist,

```
function set_new_author_base() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $author_slug = 'artist';
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = $author_slug;
}
add_action('init', 'set_new_author_base');
```

In the author.php template i query the $author-ID posts in the custom post type 'ideas':

```
<?php 
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
query_posts('post_type=ideas&author='.$curauth->ID.'&posts_per_page=1&paged='.$paged);
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php endwhile;
previous_posts_link('newer');
next_posts_link('older');
endif;
?>
```

for some reason i get a 404, 
in the other side, i can run queries in taxonomy.php, home.php, index.php... with pagination also and it works fine.

i see the next and previous links that point me here: `http://domain.dev/artist/philip/page/2/`
but i get the 404 error,

the query in home.php template:

```
<?php //*The Query*//
query_posts($query_string . '&post_type=ideas&posts_per_page=1&offset=0&paged='.$paged);
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
```

here i correctly get next and previous posts http://domain.dev/ideas/page/2/

the query in index.php template:

```
<?php //*The Query*//
query_posts($query_string . '&posts_per_page=1&offset=0&paged='.$paged);
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
```

here i correctly get next and previous posts http://domain.dev/ideas/page/2/

do you understand what is going on here???
i'm sure that the author have some posts, i have flush the rules...

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found a solution to my problem!

```
function custom_author_archive( &$query ) {
    if ($query->is_author)
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'idea' );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_author_archive' );
```