# next_posts_link and previous_posts_link problem

Tags: theme-development, archives, custom-post-type-archives, next-post-link, author-template

Below is the code from my author.php file. The problem is that `next_posts_link` and `previous_posts_link` only generate links based on the number of posts in the blog authored by the author in question, not the number of posts in the query ( which includes pages and events). I have used WP_Query to add the custom post type 'events' as recommended [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26794/the-author-posts-link-for-authors-of-custom-post-types). I find this behaviour strange because the page is displaying the results of the query but the `previous/next_posts_link's` are doing something completely different. Can anyone see my mistake or is this some problem with WordPress.

```
<?php get_header(); 
// add evemts post type to query          
$query = new WP_Query( array( 
  'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page', 'events' ) 
  ));

  if($query->have_posts()) : ?>
  <h2 class="title">Posted by : author </h2>
   <div id="main">
        <div id="content">                                  
            <?php while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>        
            <div class="archive-post" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">                  
                <div class="blog-entry">
                <h3 class="blog-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>                                   
            <div class="entry-meta">Entry meta here</div>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <div class="entry-utility">                                                                                                
              <?php edit_post_link( 'Edit', '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
            </div>
          </div>                  
            </div> <!-- .post -->            
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>                         


          <!-- navigation -->
            <div class="navigation clear">
                <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
                <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
            </div>


    </div>  <!-- end #content -->        
  <?php get_sidebar(); ?>    
  </div><!-- #main -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**EDIT** : I have just found [this](http://designrjc.com/fix-previous_posts_link-and-next_posts_link-for-custom-post-types/) page detailing the problem, however after implementing the solution, while it is definitely an improvement in that the links now show, still for some reason they point me to a 404 page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, first by implementing [the solution](http://designrjc.com/fix-previous_posts_link-and-next_posts_link-for-custom-post-types/) I described in the edit above, and then by adding the code below ( from [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35380/pagination-in-author-php-template-returns-404-error) ) to functions.php. By the way I actually still had a problem at that point with a 404 on the last page which [seemingly](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/query-posts-pagination-404) is caused by having 'posts_per_page' set to less than the value in the WordPress settings, I was happy to use the WordPress settings myself so I just left it out of the query.

```
    function custom_author_archive( &$query ) {
    if ($query->is_author)
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'events' ) );
    }
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_author_archive' );
```

Answer (score 2):

When using custom post types I got around this problem by using the following code. Of course you will need to put in the HTML for how you want it to display on your site.

```
<?php 

    $temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query= null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $wp_query->query(''); // Enter you query here

 ?>

<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

// Post body

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php previous_posts_link('Previous page'); ?>
<?php next_posts_link('Next page'); ?>

<?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;?>
```

Comment: Thanks, This may work but I actually got it working see my answer. Also I was a bit reluctant to query directly in WP. I usually manage to avoid it.